# D/skia ( 8919): Shader compilation error_ Help me solve this problem

Tags: flutter-layout

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/Choreographer( 8919): Skipped 218 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 8919): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f885ae0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x8732ce90)
I/OpenGLRenderer( 8919): Davey! duration=5004ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=28978637647800, Vsync=28982270980988, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=28982277777820, AnimationStart=28982277869920, PerformTraversalsStart=28982281804220, DrawStart=28982298938620, SyncQueued=28982312673220, SyncStart=28982336675620, IssueDrawCommandsStart=28982450126320, SwapBuffers=28982885248420, FrameCompleted=28983666130020, DequeueBufferDuration=527796000, QueueBufferDuration=4732000, 
D/EGL_emulation( 8919): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9ce94f60: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xededdde0)
I/Choreographer( 8919): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/skia    ( 8919): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 8919): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 8919): Errors:
D/skia    ( 8919): 

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 37 pixels on the bottom.

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Padding file:///C:/Users/OROAD/AndroidStudioProjects/enichat/lib/screens/registration_screen.dart:24:13
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#4c912 relayoutBoundary=up2 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(24.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=363.4, 0.0<=h<=401.4)
...  size: Size(363.4, 401.4)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: center
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: stretch
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/skia    ( 8919): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 8919): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 8919): Errors:
D/skia    ( 8919): 
D/skia    ( 8919): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 8919): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 8919): Errors:
D/skia    ( 8919): 
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:312)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:93)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/flutter ( 8919): PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference, null)
D/skia    ( 8919): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 8919): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 8919): Errors:
D/skia    ( 8919): 

════════ (2) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 37 pixels on the bottom.
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Padding file:///C:/Users/OROAD/AndroidStudioProjects/enichat/lib/screens/login_screen.dart:22:13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleSignInWithCredential(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:478)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:120)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 8919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/flutter ( 8919): PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)' on a null object reference, null)
```